# Tool for dynamic documentation of AWS architecture with service details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Which tool [or combination of tools] could I use that,
given the AWS creds [or an IAM user] can map the AWS architecture of a system?
For example , say I have 5 EC2 instances behind an ELB with 2 elastic IPS with 1 RDS and a second  synchronised replica along with an SQS .

I would like to implement a tool that [given the right creds] could give a 10.000 feet view of all the architecture [instance ids, types, status, IPs, links, sec group rules, keys etc] and then drill down on a component [eg an EC2 instance] and have more details [OS, nginx/apache configuration etc].

Something like [this](http://creately.com/draw-amazon-architecture-diagrams) but dynamic [updated based on changes I do in AWS] and details that I define.

Comment: cloudformation + cloudformer?

Comment: Questions that start with "is there a tool..." are generally considered off-topic, since they answers may become obsolete and the questions tend to attract answers that are opinionated or thinly-veiled product promotion, or outright spam.